# Odoo v12 Many2many Fields in calendar view

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I can succesfully display many2many fields in the form view:

[image]

but when I try to display it in the calendar view I get "No Records" or "X records" but not the field content.

[image]

This is the field in my model:

```
user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', 'events_user_rel', 'user_id', 'id', string='Event users', select= True, track_visibility='onchange')
```

this is the code in the view:

```
<record id="view_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">my.model</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="my.view_calendar"/>
    <field eval="2" name="priority"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//calendar" position="replace">
          <calendar color="event_id" date_start="date_start" date_stop="date_end" string="Events" all_day="date_start" mode="month">
            <field name="user_ids"/>
          </calendar>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

What should I do to get the values "Joel Willis, etc.." in the calendar view

Comment: do you remember how you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Try `<field name="user_ids" write_model="res.users" write_field="name"/>`.

See an example at `<path_to_v12>/addons/calendar/views/calendar_views.xml` lines 266-281. Those parameters are used at `<path_to_v12>/addons/web/static/src/js/views/calendar/calendar_view.js` lines 63-94.

Comment: Hi Adan, thanks for your reply. Unfortunatelly that didnt work. Adding those parameters to "field", adds a new panel below the month calendar as shown in the attached image: https://imgur.com/qz4Zp8N , wich currently resolves another problem I had, so your reply was very helpful. Would you have any other suggestion please let me know

Comment: Following your reply I got a little further by adding the following: `<field name="user_ids" write_model="res.partner" write_field="user_ids" avatar_field="image_small"/>` I get this https://imgur.com/sy8sUOb

Answer (score 1):

If instead of having a many-to-many relationship with `res.users` you define a relationship to `res.partner` you may use the `many2manyattendee` widget

```
<field name="partner_ids" widget="many2manyattendee"/>
```

Just be aware that this widget is designed to work with `res.partner` only.

See `<path_to_v12>/addons/calendar/static/src/js/base_calendar.js` and `<path_to_v12>/addons/calendar/static/tests/calendar_tests.js`

Comment: I will give this a try, it looks promising !